# Network X remove edges and put it back

Tags: python, networkx

Hi is there a way to put the edges back after removing the edges from networkx?
The reason I remove it at first place is because I need to group the connected edges based on the attribute.

```
import networkx
  
# To create an empty undirected graph
G = networkx.Graph()
  
# To add a node
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
G.add_node(4)
G.add_node(7)
G.add_node(9)
G.add_node(10)
G.add_node(11)
G.add_node(12)
G.add_node(13)
G.add_node(14)
G.add_node(15)
  
# To add an edge

G.add_edge(1,2, color="r", asset="A1")
G.add_edge(3,1,color="r", asset="A2")
G.add_edge(2,4,color="b", asset="A3")
G.add_edge(4,1,color="b", asset="A4")
G.add_edge(9,1,color="e", asset="A5")
G.add_edge(1,7,color="d", asset="A6")
G.add_edge(2,9,color="d", asset="A7")
G.add_edge(10,11,color="d", asset="A8")
G.add_edge(11,12,color="e", asset="A9")
G.add_edge(12,13,color="c", asset="A10")
G.add_edge(14,15,color="c", asset="A11")

# Then I would like to remove edges that has color 'e'. So when I do :
for c in nx.connected_components(G):
    attribute = nx.get_edge_attributes(G.subgraph(c),"asset")
    print("attribute", attribute)
attribute {(1, 2): 'A1', (1, 3): 'A2', (1, 4): 'A4', (1, 7): 'A6', (2, 4): 'A3', (2, 9): 'A7'}
attribute {(10, 11): 'A8'}
attribute {(12, 13): 'A10'}
attribute {(14, 15): 'A11'}

# this way I can put them into a separate group because if there is color'e' 
#in the edges, then i  would assign the next connected components to a new group.
```

Then  i need the edges with color='e' in the networkx again because i need to assign them to the group before it (I can take care of this). But does anyone know if there is a way to put edges back to networkx or is there a way to get the expected output without having to remove the edges?
Since I create all the node using momepy, if there is any inbuilt function that i can use from momepy, then that is even better, otherwise i am happy with other solution

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is probably to make a *copy* of G, and remove the edges from the copy so that you can always access the original graph G.  For instance, consider the following:

```
H = G.copy()

for v,w,d in G.edges(data=True):
    if d['color']=='e':
        H.remove_edge(v,w)

for c in nx.connected_components(H):
    attribute = nx.get_edge_attributes(H.subgraph(c),"asset")
    print("attribute", attribute)
```

leads to the desired result

```
attribute {(1, 2): 'A1', (1, 3): 'A2', (1, 4): 'A4', (1, 7): 'A6', (2, 4): 'A3', (2, 9): 'A7'}
attribute {(10, 11): 'A8'}
attribute {(12, 13): 'A10'}
attribute {(14, 15): 'A11'}
```